# Why is This Not Sorting the Newly Added Number?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a new pizza to the list so that it automatically resorts itself back into the list in numerical order. The problem is that it the new pizza "Thai" either doesn't show up or it doesn't resort itself the way that it should. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
toppings = ['pepponi', 'pineapple', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'olives', 'anchovies', 'mushrooms']

prices = ['2', '6', '1', '3', '2', '7', '2']

num_pizzas = len(toppings)

pizzas = list(zip(prices, toppings))

print("We sell " + str(num_pizzas) + " different kinds of pizza!")

print("\n" + "Pizzas That We Sell:")

pizzas.sort()



print (pizzas)

cheapest_pizza = pizzas

priciest_pizza = pizzas[-1]

print("\n" + "The Most Expensive Pizza is:")
print(priciest_pizza)


three_cheapest = pizzas[:3]
print("\n" + "The Three Cheapest Pizzas:")
print(three_cheapest)

num_two_dollar_slices = prices.count("2")
print(num_two_dollar_slices)

prices.append('10')
toppings.append('Thai')

pizzas = list(zip(prices, toppings))

new_pizza_list = sorted(pizzas)

print(new_pizza_list)
```

What am I doing wrong? At the last one, it shows that it's not reorganizing, and I feel like I must be doing something wrong because it shouldn't be this hard to add to the list. Here's the input that I get:

```
We sell 7 different kinds of pizza!

Pizzas That We Sell:
[('1', 'cheese'), ('2', 'mushrooms'), ('2', 'olives'), ('2', 'pepponi'), 
('3', 'sausage'), ('6', 'pineapple'), ('7', 'anchovies')]

The Most Expensive Pizza is:
('7', 'anchovies')

The Three Cheapest Pizzas:
[('1', 'cheese'), ('2', 'mushrooms'), ('2', 'olives')]
3
[('1', 'cheese'), ('10', 'Thai'), ('2', 'mushrooms'), ('2', 'olives'), ('2', 
'pepponi'), ('3', 'sausage'), ('6', 'pineapple'), ('7', 'anchovies')]
```

As you can see, the Thai is the second pizza when it should be the last. I've tried multiple ways of resorting it, but it's not rearranging it.

Comment: Hint: Why are you storing the prices as strings?

Comment: "10" is greater than "1" and less than "2". It's right where it should be. Use numbers if you want the sorting to be numeric.

Comment: Which sorting numeric will return an error from zipping int and string, you know a dictionary would probably work really well in this case. You could sort the keys/prices numerically

Answer (score 3):

As jwodder pointed out a solution would be to use integer values for the prices instead of strings. If you preferred to stick to strings (for whatever reason) you could use the following instead of `sorted(pizzas)`:

```
sorted(pizzas, key=lambda a: int(a[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Jwodder mentioned that you are storing the prices as strings, Which kinda messes up the sort, and Jschnoor's method was brilliant too! But I suggest storing data into a dictionary for easier manipulation (although you cannot sort the dictionaries, it would be more uniform to extract data as well)

```
pizzas = {
    'pepponi' : 2,
    'pineapple' : 6,
    'cheese': 1,
    'sausage' : 3,
    'olives' : 2,
    'anchovies' : 7,
    'mushrooms' : 2,
    'rice'  : 2,
    'dogs'  : 4,
    'cats'  : 2
    }
pizzas_list = zip(pizzas.values(), pizzas.keys())
```

You cannot sort the zipped list, but you can use sorted (becasue sorted() does not touch the original list)

```
sorted_pizzas_list = sorted(pizzas_list)
```

The code above returns

```
[(1, 'cheese'), (2, 'cats'), (2, 'mushrooms'), (2, 'olives'), (2, 'pepponi'), (2, 'rice'), (3, 'sausage'), (4, 'dogs'), (6, 'pineapple'), (7, 'anchovies')]
```

and just use `NAME_OF_DICT.update({'item3': 3})` to add an item on your dict.
for example:

```
pizzas.update({'noodles': 4})
#Take note of the {} after the ()
```